# Android: choose location of included View in xml

Tags: android, android-xml, android-view

I'm building an app with game cards and I'm looking into creating a custom View that has an ordinary card with a front and back that once clicked will be turned over from front to back.

I'v been using the [Flip3DAnimation tutorial](http://www.inter-fuser.com/2009/08/android-animations-3d-flip.html) tutorial inorder to achieve the flipping of the card from front to back and it works perfectly. but after working on the app for a while I saw that there will be a serious problem on the next part of my app which is gonna be dragging and dropping of the card across the screen.

when I spoke to JakeWharton on the freenode chat this morning, I thought I should create an XML view and include it in the `main.xml`.

the problem is that when I try to move the included view around all I achieve is getting the image stuck to the top left. **Question: How can I move the included xml around the parent View?**

**Code for Card:**

```
<ViewFlipper xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="80dp"
    android:layout_height="108dp"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/c2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />

</ViewFlipper>
```

---

**Code for `main.xml`:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/Board"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="top"
    android:background="@drawable/pinecropped" >

    <include
        android:id="@+id/firstCard"
        android:layout_marginRight="91dp"
        android:layout_marginTop="102dp"
        layout="@layout/card" />

</FrameLayout>
```

---

here is what I get as the graphical layout:

[image: graphical layout]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

in the end I just created a different Class to handle the cards and had a layout in `main.xml` to represent it in the main activity code.

Comment: didn't the workaround I suggested above work? overriding layout_width and layout_height in the include element.

Comment: nope, since `include` puts the child xml in a `FrameLayout` and that is what changes there is no affect on the included xml file

Answer (score 2):

In card.xml change:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/c2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondImage"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

To:

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/firstImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/c2" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/secondImage"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/back" />
```

Always know you can use the tool [HierarchyViewer](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/debugging/debugging-ui.html) to debug such problems, I guess you would have seen the cards actually take up the entire screen, and that's why they attach to top.

UPDATE:

It seems to in order to override layout_* attributes in  tags you'll have to override both layout_height and layout_width, see bug and workaround here:
http://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=2863#c9

Comment: gave it a try, did not do anything. :( I'll look into the hierarchyViewer

Comment: Didn't see you've specified fixed size in the FrameLayout, so it wasn't that. See my update to my answer above for a possible solution